# Effective Extensions for Development Wiki

Tags: plugins, mediawiki, wiki

Our small team of 3-4 developers uses a wiki for documentation and collaboration.  I'm trying to put together a list of some solid extensions which would help make it better.  We are using MediaWiki, but if you know of a good extension/plug-in for another platform I'd like to hear about that too.  Thanks.

Here is my list so far:

- [Geshi](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/) for syntax highlighting.
- FCKeditor
- TagAsCategory

Promising Extensions that don't work w/ MediaWiki 1.15.0

- CategoryEditor
- IssueTracker

Comment: I found a fairly hidden link on mediwiki.org -
http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Category:Must-have_extensions

also

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Category:Corporate_Must-have_extensions

Seems to be some more promising extensions there as well.

Answer (score 1):

Two things come to mind:

- Bug tracking tool integration
- SCM tool integration

For MediaWiki there are already

Bugzilla integration:

- http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:BugzillaReports

SVN integration:

- http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SVNIntegration

The whole list of extensions is [here](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension_Matrix)

Comment: Thanks, I have seen the list before, its just too many things to wade through though.  Also, seems like whenever I find something that might be useful, its broken :(

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think that a good starting point would be to check what we use at [mediawiki.org](http://mediawiki.org), because this is a Development Wiki :)

My first choice would be [CodeReview](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:CodeReview) of course. It's not pretty, but it's very useful. See [how we use it](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:Code/MediaWiki): it allows to integrate a SVN into the wiki, to add comments on code, tag commits, and put statuses on it. 
At MediaWiki, we use new/verified/ok chain, adding fixme/reverted/resolved/deferred when things go wrong; but you're free to use your own statuses here.

Comment: We are using VSTS for our source control.